# Retrive data using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp and i want to find data that has been created

This is my sql function works 
Select Trv_No from Ticket_LO

This is my model in cakephp

```
$ticket = $this->Ticket->find('first', array('conditions' => array('AND' => array('Ticket.TRV_No' => $trv_no)));
    if(empty($ticket))
    {
        $table_name = 'Ticket_L0';
        $this->Ticket->setSource($table_name);
        //$ticket = $this->Ticket->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Ticket.TRV_No' => $trv_no)));
        $ticket = $this->Ticket->find('first', array('conditions' => array('AND' => array('Ticket.TRV_No' => $trv_no, 'Ticket.HIDDEN_STAT LIKE' =>'0'))));
        if(empty($ticket)) { return false; } else { return true; }
    }
    else
    { return true; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first,

You don't need to set `$this->Ticket->setSource($table_name);` in your model.

You can use `$this->find`

I'm not sure what do you really want. But, I guess you want something like that.

```
$ticket = $this->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
         'Ticket.TRV_No' => $trv_no,
         'Ticket.HIDDEN_STAT'=> 0 //if you want to find 0 only, you don't need LIKE. But, if you want some string, you can use something like 'Ticket.HIDDEN_STAT LIKE'=>'yourString%'
     )
   )
);
```

And, you can add your condition after that.

```
if(!empty($ticket)) return true;
else return false;
```